# Heatmap chart for oracle APEX application

Tags: oracle-apex

I need an Heatmap chart for my oracle APEX application. I can see two products here "Anychart" and "Anychart for Oracle APEX". So which product should I use for Heatmaps in Oracle APEX5

Comment: What have you researched so far?

Comment: Which ones have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

Since APEX uses AnyChart licensed charts I was hoping the heatmap that is available in the AnyChart flash maps package would be available in the APEX charts wizard. It is not however as Oracle apparently did not buy all of the AnyChart Flash Map package from information found in the link below.

https://community.oracle.com/thread/1099149

In fact it would be a violation to to try and implement the heatmap from that package in APEX from this response from Oracle on the subject.

"Any attempt to unbundle the AnyChart Flash Chart Component from an Oracle product, or to use the AnyChart Flash Chart Component outside of the Oracle product will be in violation of this license and will result in the immediate termination of this license."

I know this is not an answer for you, but I am still searching for a good solution to this issue for my own use.